# Overlap two shapefiles with geopandas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, merge, gis, shapefile, geopandas

I have these two shapefiles.
[First shapefile with Provinces on link 1]
[Second shapefile with Districts on link 2]

I need to join/merge these two shapefiles to return a map as below:
[![Mozambique Districts as Map below]

moz_admin=[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hZIB.png): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MYNkuKFXP0dt76G9OgeBotjF5UmiRqEl/view?usp=sharing

moz_admin_district=[2]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idf5VKgN8PZgdoAcBVEcY9pDa1WYpg7-/view?usp=sharing

[image: Mozambique Districts on link 3]

What I have done so far:

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd

file = os.listdir(r'pathtofilefolder')
path = [os.path.join(r'folder', i) for i in file if ".shp" in i]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gpd.read_file(i) for i in path], 
                        ignore_index=True), crs=gpd.read_file(path[0]).crs)
```

and

```
moz_admin.to_crs(moz_admin_district.crs, inplace=True) #Change projections
gpd.sjoin(moz_admin_district, moz_admin, how='union', op='within').shape #Join 2 shapefiles
gpd.sjoin(moz_admin_district, moz_admin, how='union', op='within').plot()
```

and

```
diffs = []
gdfs = [moz_admin, moz_admin_district]
    for idx, gdf in enumerate(gdfs):
    if idx < 2:
        diffs.append(gdf.symmetric_difference(gdfs[idx+1]).iloc[0])
diffs.append(moz_admin_district.iloc[0].geometry)
```

and

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([moz_admin, moz_admin_district]))
```

and

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
res_union = gpd.overlay(moz_admin, moz_admin_district, how='union')
```

and

```
so = moz_admin.merge(moz_admin_district, on='ADM1_PT', how='inner')
df  = tab_df.merge(spatial_df, on='mukey', how='right')
sof = gpd.GeoDataFrame(so)
```

and

```
merged_master = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.merge(moz_admin, moz_admin_district, how='left', left_on="ADM1_PT", right_on="ADM1_PT"))
merged = merged_master[['ADM1_PT', 'ADM2_PT', 'geometry']]
```

and

```
so = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([moz_admin, moz_admin_district], ignore_index=True))
```

and

```
sjoined_listings = gpd.sjoin(moz_admin_district, moz_admin, op='intersects')
```

and

```
merged=sjoin(moz_admin_district, moz_admin, how='left', op='intersects')
```

Without success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#OVERLAP TWO SHAPEFILES INTO ONE

ax = moz_admin.plot(color='none', edgecolor='black', linewidths=1.5)
moz_admin_district.plot(ax=ax, color='none', edgecolor='grey', linewidths=0.5)
```

[image]